# when was "well" first used to begin a sentence in england

Tags: etymology

In writing the supposed memoirs of a late eighteenth century widow I'm wondering when "Well" at the beginning of a sentence was first known to have been used.

Comment: [Shakespeare](https://books.google.nl/books?id=PTcrAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA301&lpg=PA301&dq=shakespeare+%22well,+well,+well%22&source=bl&ots=w388XTpWQf&sig=ACfU3U1L2wXoMsobbXlZI8lyvwAKeNN5nA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwie49-f1ubjAhVEJlAKHWflDW0Q6AEwCHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=shakespeare%20%22well%2C%20well%2C%20well%22&f=false) already used it: "Well, well, I see I talk but idly, and you mock at me." (Richard II, act 3)

Comment: About 200 years before it was documented.

Comment: Well before people learned to start sentences with a capital letter, likewise the names of countries, and finish questions with a question (interrogation) mark.

Answer (score 3):

[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/226983) (paywalled) has it used as an interjection in Old English, and has a substantive citation in Middle English from the fourteenth century:

> **well,** *adv.* and *n.4*
>
> **V.** In disjunctive use (sometimes as a simple interjection).
>    **20.** Used to introduce a remark or statement, sometimes implying that the speaker or writer accepts a situation, etc., already expressed or indicated, or desires to qualify this in some way, but frequently used only as a preliminary or resumptive word.
>   <sub>Well functions as a discourse marker, often expressing an emotion such as surprise, indignation, resignation, or relief, but also used when pausing to consider one's next words, to introduce an explanation or amplification, to mark the resumption or end of a conversation, etc., or to indicate that one is waiting for an answer or explanation from someone.</sub>
>
> **a.** Not combined with another expression.
>   <sub>In Old English apparently only after *wel lā int.*   with intervening noun (as vocative); see ***wella*** int. 1, and cf. discussion in etymology.</sub>
>
> > eOE   King Ælfred tr. Boethius *De Consol. Philos.* (Otho) (2009) I. xxxi. 531   Wella wisan men, wel, gað ealle on þone weg [etc.].
> >
> > c1330  *Sir Tristrem* (1886) l. 2950 (*MED*)   Wel, whi seistow so?

Comment: It would be interesting to see if it came over with the Germanic _wohl_ / Dutch _wol_ too.

Comment: Not convinced that "came over with" is entirely appropriate for OE, but OED says it's cognate with many Old Dutch, Old Low German, Old High German, Norse, whatever, words including the modern German *wohl*. However, I'm not sure whether the modern Germanic languages use *wohl* in this interjectory sense [and that's out of scope for this site: you could try asking on [german.se]].

Comment: This. By the fifteenth century, it is quite common. In *Le Morte Darthur*, several characters use *well* to introduce statements, including Arthur, Merlin, Tristram, Palomides, Morgan, and others. Even a cursory search of the full text here ( https://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/MaloryWks2 ) yields many results, with "well" or "wel" often appearing before "said (character)."